# How to make a marker tag like uber?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, bitmap, google-maps-markers

I want to diplay a tag like in the uber app next to my marker. How do I make a tag like this in google map?

I already try adding a title and a snippet. But its not what I'm quite lookoing for.

```
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(MELBOURNE)
                        .title("6 min away")
                        .snippet("Pick up point ")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pickup_2x)));
```

[image]

This is what i got with @Nirmal  answer. Its still not what I want exactly 
[image: This is what i got with @Nirmal answer. Its still not what I want exactly]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

info_window_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <wm.com.taxiapp.view.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_distance"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/space_10"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/space_10"
        android:text="2\nMIN"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_8" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_scheduled_ride"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/space_10"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/space_10"
        android:src="@drawable/time"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <wm.com.taxiapp.view.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_lat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/space_5"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/space_5"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/space_3dp"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:text=" "
            android:textColor="@color/hintColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_12" />

        <wm.com.taxiapp.view.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_lng"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/space_100"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/space_3dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/space_5"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/hintColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_12" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Inflate this layout file in info window `mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter`

Comment: this doesn't help. Still its not what i want. I edited my post with image i got with your answer.

Comment: you have to implement infowindow on map and inflate this layout into your info window.

Comment: oh, ok, I got it now. I have done inflate it with `getInfoContents`, not with `getInfoWindow`.
Thanks again!

Comment: @NirmalPrajapat What is *wm.com.taxiapp.view.CustomTextView* here ?

Comment: @JayRathodRJ , I just customised the TextView, you can customise or use the normal TextView.